Android Auto Change Title Color
I'm new to working with Android Auto and am using react-native-carplay to develop the pane template. I'm having an issue with text styles and don't have any idea how to change the title color. Does anyone know how to set the color for the detailText title?
import { PaneTemplate } from "react-native-carplay";

export const paneTemplate = new PaneTemplate({
    pane: {
        items: [
            {
                text: 'Pane',
                detailText: 'Detail Text',
            },
        ],
    },
    title: 'Pane',
    headerAction: { type: 'back' },
});

Android Auto module
import { CarPlay } from 'react-native-carplay';
import { tabBarTemplate } from './templates/tab-bar.template';

export function AndroidAutoModule() {
  console.debug('[AndroidAutoModule]')
  CarPlay.emitter.addListener('didConnect', () => {
    CarPlay.setRootTemplate(paneTemplate);
  });
  CarPlay.emitter.addListener('backButtonPressed', () => {
    CarPlay.popTemplate();
  });
}


Try to code below
import { PaneTemplate } from "react-native-carplay";

// Define your styles for title and detailText
const titleStyle = {
  textColor: '#FF0000', // Replace with your desired color
};

export const paneTemplate = new PaneTemplate({
  pane: {
    items: [
      {
        text: 'Pane',
        detailText: 'Detail Text',
      },
    ],
  },
  title: 'Pane',
  headerAction: { type: 'back' },
  style: {
    title: titleStyle, // Apply the title style
  },
});

